# "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"

Tags: c#

For creating a list with 100 random number between 0 and 1 I wrote below code that I receive the error.

```
      public List<float> random()
        {
            List<float> storerandomvalues = new List<float>(100);
            Random randomvalues = new Random();
            float randomnum;
            for (int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++)
            {
                randomnum = 0f;
                randomnum = randomvalues.Next(1);
                storerandomvalues[counter]= randomnum;           //the error
            }
            return storerandomvalues;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`List<T>.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method instead, `storerandomvalues` is not an array.You can't add items with indexer to a generic list.You can use indexer only to change existing items.

```
storerandomvalues.Add(randomnum);
```

Answer (score 7):

You're creating empty `storerandomvalues` (without any items). Parameter in the `List<>` constructor is the list capacity only.

The best solution in your case is to use array instead of `List<>` (because in your case the number of items in the collection is constant):

```
var storerandomvalues = new int[100];
Random randomvalues = new Random();
float randomnum;
for (int counter = 0; counter < storerandomvalues.Length; counter++)
{
    randomnum = 0f;
    randomnum = randomvalues.Next(1);
    storerandomvalues[counter] = randomnum;        
}
return storerandomvalues;
```

Comment: Even if it's constant in this method it does not mean that there won't be added numbers later.

Comment: Yes maybe, but using `List.Add` in the loop, when the count of iterations is constant ... it is very bad practice.

Comment: @Alexander - Why is that a bad practice?  I totally dis-agree.

Comment: Thank you @Alexander. If I want to define this array "storerandomvalues" as global. what should I do?

Comment: @user3371238 just add `private readonly int[] _storerandomvalues = new int[100]` in your class.

Comment: sorry I could not get your mean? @Alexander

Comment: @Alexander: but if the method should return a `List<T>` because it should be a mutable collection you have to use `List.Add` even if the size is constant initially. An array is appropriate if it shouldn't be possible to modify the collection.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
storerandomvalues.Add(randomnum);
```

not

```
storerandomvalues[counter]= randomnum;
```