# Error "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index"

Tags: c#

I tried the script by changing

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < i_f.Length; ii++)
```

into

```
for (int ii = 0; ii < 100; ii++)
```

but I still got the same error

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index

```
float[][] b = Enumerable.Range(0, 1143600).Select(j => new float[100]).ToArray();
float[] i_f = new float[100];
List<float> storerandomvalues = new List<float>(100);
```

---

```
public float Error(int itemid)
{
    float error= 0f;
    float[] i_f = b[itemid];
    for (int ii = 0; ii < i_f.Length; ii++)
    {
        error += storerandomvalues[ii] * i_f[ii];     //error line
    }
    error = 1-error;
    return error;
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130796/index-was-out-of-range-must-be-non-negative-and-less-than-the-size-of-the-coll)

Comment: If you really want to use that indexer then just turn that list into an array.don't use list

Comment: I posted by myself. That one is completely different @Alexander

Comment: No, that is _exatcly_ the same.

Comment: storerandomvalues[ii] --> that is error, collection length is smaller than that iteration

Comment: No @Selman22. During that one,I just create a list and fill it with random numbers.Now , I must to multiply that list with an array (like matrix multiplication) ans save the result in error.By the way, if I want to define public array for that one instead of list "var storerandomvalues = new int[100];" it shows an error about var (it can not define as public vaiable)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you added anything to the `storerandomvalues` list, you just initialized its *capacity*.  The List(int) constructor **does not add anything to the list**, it just makes the backing storage large enough to hold 100 items.  If you want to initialize something to a fixed number of items, you really should be using an array, not a list:

```
float[] storerandomvalues = new float[100];
```

Alternatively, you should adjust your loop condition so that it checks the length of both `storerandomvalues` *and* `i_f` so that the index can't wander out of range of either of them.